# How to get class in parent from element in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I need to write a test to check if the parent to a div has a specific class, in this case "parent".

I have this code:

```
....
<div class="parent">
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>
....
```

What I have tried:

```
element(by.id('child')).getWebElement().getDriver().getAttribute('class');
```

But I get the following error and have no idea how to continue..

```
.getWebElement(...).getDriver(...).getText is not a function
```

Answer (score 7):

You aren't getting the parent properly. It's easiest to do this with xpath:

```
element(by.id('child')).element(by.xpath('..')).getAttribute('class');
```

In this example, `by.xpath('..')` should select the parent element.

Comment: Thanks !! (please @SannaWidell mark as solved if solved)

Answer (score 3):

You can tweak your code as:

```
let child = element(by.id('child')).getWebElement();
let parent = child.getDriver().findElement(by.tagName('div'));
expect(parent.getAttribute('class')).toBe('parent');
```

`getAttribute()` will not work with `getDriver()` directly since it returns [browser](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getDriver) object.

Answer (score 0):

If you [don't want to use xpath](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide#locator-strategies) you can for example revert the logic.

`element(by.css('div.parent > div[id="child"]'))`